having problem understanding cloudflare R2 API philosophy and security
after two days browsing through their poor documentation i'm still having problems grasping how exactly R2 manages security per bucket, and how should i handle it via API.
basically i'm building a multitenancy app, which should create new bucket per new registered client, setup bucket specific credentials (whatever they are for R2, token ID/token secret, API token or something else...), store the credentials in a client specific db and then obviously use those credentials for storage operations in the buckets. these credentials should be bucket specific, so that no client can access a bucket that does not belong to its account.
i'm trying to utilize the S3 API, which seems to create new bucket without problems, using R2 admin credentials (ID/Secret) for all buckets, however i fail when it comes to creating credentials for that specific buckets. here R2 seems to differ from s3 which uses IAM user/authentication as far as i can understand, however r2 probably requires r2 specific tokens that need to be generated via cloudflare API?
first of all am i correct in my approach to assume that client specific bucket is the way to go for multitenancy, and how do you scale this beyond the 1000 buckets limit per r2 account?
second, do i understand correctly the whole credentials/authentication approach and differences between s3 and r2, what are the steps for creating bucket, credentials for it, and subsequently performing r/w operations in the bucket using these credentials?
thank you!
i tried creating bucket specific credentials via cloudflare api which seems to create workers r/w credentials, however i'm not sure whether these are the right credentials that i need, considering i do not use any workers in my code?
bucket creation via s3 api works without any problems, however i struggle when it comes to what type of authentication should i use from that point onwards and how to generate it via api?
